# Canvas drawImage with video while fullscreen not working when source video is visible

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-canvas, html5-video

I am currently working on showing some parts of a video by drawing them on canvas while showing the main part of the video as a video tag. Recently I ran into a weird situation where the canvas part stops drawing when it goes into full-screen mode on an older mobile phone(galaxy 7). It works fine on recent phones and PC.

So, I fiddled around and found out that drawImage will stop drawing in full-screen mode if the video is visible.

https://jsfiddle.net/2c8udb7j/1/

https://jsfiddle.net/2c8udb7j/2/

The two are same except that the second one has the line `video.style.display = "none"`. Everything else is the same. You can check by clicking the 'play' button and then the 'fullscreen' button.

Anyone experience this issue or know about it or have a solution?

**The fiddle code**

html

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/hls.js/latest/hls.min.js"></script>
  <script src="MultiviewCore.js"></script>
  <button onclick='video.play();'>play</button>
  <button onclick='video.pause();'>pause</button>
  <button onclick='document.body.requestFullscreen();'>fullscreen</button>
  <div id='container'></div>
</body>
```

script

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container')
var myRange = document.getElementById('myRange')
var video = document.createElement('video')
video.setAttribute("playsinline", "")
video.src = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.width = 512
canvas.height = 384
canvas.style.width = '512px'
canvas.style.height = '384px'
video.style.width = '512px'
video.style.height = '384px'
video.style.display = "none" // the only difference

function updateCanvas() {
  ctx.drawImage(video,
                0,
                0,
                video.videoWidth,
                video.videoHeight,
                0,
                0,
                canvas.width,
                canvas.height);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(updateCanvas)
}

document.body.appendChild(canvas)
document.body.appendChild(video)

updateCanvas()
```

**EDIT :**
Just realized I'm testing this with chrome only. Tried it with galaxy 7's basic internet browser and full-screen drawImage works fine. Maybe a chrome or chromium issue?

Comment: Can repro on a Galaxy S6. You can open an issue at https://crbug.com Also you may let them know that even `createImageBitmap` and `ImageCapture.grabFrame` are affected, capturing a transparent frame of the correct dimensions.

Comment: @Kaiido thx for checking the issue. I've already sent a bug report with the fiddle.

Comment: could you link to that bug report? I can't find it.

Comment: @Kaiido Ah, I reported it with chrome browser, not to the chromium bug report link you mentioned. Will there be a lot of difference on how they respond to the bug? If so, I'll make a new bug report with your link. Also, I'm not clear on exactly how `createImageBitmap` and `ImageCapture.grabFrame` are effected, so I'll report just my version of the bug. Maybe you can append your's to mine(not sure if that's possible) or you should report it separately.